# facebook post photo on the friends wall

Tags: android, android-facebook

I want to post on friends wall and encountered difficulties.

First i uploaded the photo on my wall:

```
Request.Callback requestCallback = new Request.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    Log.d("exception","error");
                                }

                                Object graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getProperty("id");
                                if (graphResponse == null || !(graphResponse instanceof String)) {
                                    Log.d("exception","not upload image");
                                } else {
                                    String fbPhotoAddress = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=" +graphResponse;
                                    Log.d("exception","fb="+fbPhotoAddress);
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        try {
                            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, requestCallback);
                            request.executeAsync();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

I don't know how this link (fbPhotoAddress) will be used. I read about feed dialog, it take photo post in 200x200px.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need to use facebook sdk, you can use code like the following:

```
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/png"); 
    // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("facebook") || 
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type) ) {
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  subject);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found){
            Toast.makeText(activity, type+" is not installed on the device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

but if you are using facebook sdk, you can use FacebookDialog like the following but you need to integrate with facebook so read about it:

```
     FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
    .setLink(link)
    .setApplicationName(AppConstants.FACEBOOK_DISPLAY_APP_NAME)
    .setPicture(pictureUrl)
    .setName(subject)
    //.setDescription(text)
    .build();
```

You need to ask your self also why you added this photo to your facebook account, If you made this because you do not have URL for your photo (local photo) then it will not work using the facebook url because this URL is not public. If you test it, you will find this url will view your facebook page with the photo so you need to upload your photo on any server like AWS for example then using the photo url, you can make the sharing.

Comment: Why both of your methods using facebook app? Can i post full image without it?

Comment: Yes. The user will be asked to give permission for your app on his post to let you able to post on his wall. If you do not have facebook app, the user will login using the brawser.

Comment: Picture is not shown in facebookDialog. 
Above in my code i upload picture to facebook, and get url for sharing to my friends wall. I need method for share full picture to wall. And Your method start facebook app in my app, and share message with just text.

Comment: Kindly read the last comment from my answer. It is:
You need to ask your self also why you added this photo to your facebook account, If you made this because you do not have URL for your photo (local photo) then it will not work using the facebook url because this URL is not public. If you test it, you will find this url will view your facebook page with the photo so you need to upload your photo on any server like AWS for example then using the photo url, you can make the sharing

Comment: Replace the url which you used with this url for example : http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/sky/sky-03.jpg and see if the picture appears or not. As expected, it will appears so the problem in this case will be your picture url so you need first to upload it to server then use the url for the picture.

Comment: Thx @Mina, all worked. I understood you about not public server. But FacebookDialog equivalent FeedDialog, and full image not posted on friends wall. There is problem.

Comment: I did not got u? what is the problem now?

Comment: FacebookDialog equivalent to FeedDialog, and image was posted on the my friend wall in size 200x200. But i want to share full image size (1080x1920).

Comment: FacebookDialog show dialog with image, title, description ,... so the image shown in small bix on the left.
If you need to show the image as big size, you can use Intent share which is very simple to share picture and show them in their normal size.